# is.element function in R to check character vector

Tags: r

I am using the is.element to find a particular letter is in a character vector. I start with a sequence that looks like this (DNA sequence):

```
DNA="cagcatcggctgca"
```

and then I split it using :

```
DNA_split=strsplit(DNA,split="")
```

I get

```
[[1]]
 [1] "c" "a" "g" "c" "a" "t" "c" "g" "g" "c" "t" "g" "c" "a"
```

I then use the is.element function

```
is.element("a",DNA_split)
```

and I get `[1] FALSE`.

Yet `"a"` is in the `DNA_split` vector. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"a" %in% DNA_split[[1]]` or `is.element("a",DNA_split[[1]])` or replace `DNA_split[[1]]` by `unlist(DNA_split)` since it's a list and not a vector

Answer (score 1):

Several answers possible :

```
> DNA_split
[[1]]
 [1] "c" "a" "g" "c" "a" "t" "c" "g" "g" "c" "t" "g" "c" "a"
```

So your `DNA_split` is a list and not a vector :

```
> is.list(DNA_split)
[1] TRUE
```

What you have to do is to select the vector to use `is.element()` :

```
> is.element("a", DNA_split[[1]])
[1] TRUE
```

or :

```
is.element("a", unlist(DNA_split))
```

Both `unlist(DNA_split)` and `DNA_split[[1]]` return a vector :

```
[1] "c" "a" "g" "c" "a" "t" "c" "g" "g" "c" "t" "g" "c" "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `strsplit` function is making DNA_split a list, which `is.element` can't handle. Use `unlist` to fix it.

```
DNA <- "cagcatcggctgca"
DNA_split <- strsplit(DNA, split = "")
DNA_split <- unlist(DNA_split)
is.element("a", DNA_split)
```